# Putting facebook POST response into data structure

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook

I'm playing around with getting information off facebook using jquery. I can make a post like so:

```
jQuery.post("/ajax/mercury/thread_info.php", "messages[thread_ids][id.428042003942169][offset]=0&messages[thread_ids][id.428042003942169][limit]=100&__user=618487049&&fb_dtsg=AQAYR3zl", function() {messagedata = data.repalce(/[for (;;);]+/,"");}, "json");
```

The response is a json preceded by a for(;;);

```
for (;;);
{"__ar":1,"payload":{"actions":[{"message_id":"mid.1371468351962:4b87e6feb519655468","threading_id":"\u003C1371468194477:2798341870-1905388487\u0040mail.projektitan.com>","author":"fbid ... 94692748":1363577392610,"780415542":1363581877673},"id.193214987500416":{"1336331885":1370327882640}},"payload_source":"server_fetch_thread_info"},"bootloadable":{},"ixData":[]}
```

I can't use the returned data with the for(;;); and I haven't been able to get rid of it using .replace go get it into a variable using

```
messagedata= data.repalce(/[for (;;);]+/,"")
```

Any help with how to deal with this would be appreciated.
Cheers,

Comment: Well, you can't expect "repalce" to do anything much until you at least _spell_ `replace` right ... And anyway, you should use the API instead of doing requests to undocumented endpoints.

Comment: Can't use the API, apologies for the spelling mistake.

Comment: looking at it a bit more, i can't access the returned data at all!
I get "ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Comment: Ah it was a noob error, the ajax data hadn't been received yet.
Just needed to change the call to an asynchronous one